# Why does my dataset shows column of 1st query but not of other queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, ado.net, rdlc

Why does my .xsd dataset shows column of 1 query but not other 2 queries ?

I have used 3 queries in my stored procedure and used in my dataset for RDLC report but it does show columns of 1st query only not others.

My SP:

```
create PROC  [dbo].[SelectContractorsBio]

    @GC_ID INT

AS
BEGIN    



                   Select c.Name, c.FatherName, c.Farm, cat.Name 'Cat', c.CNIC, c.EnlistmentNo, c.ContactNo,
                   CONVERT(date,c.RegistrationDate,106) as RegistrationDate, c.Email, pcat.Name 'PECCat', c.PECCategoryNo 'PECLicenseNo',
                   c.PECReceiptNo, c.ExpectedDate, c.CNWEnlistmentNo, c.NTN, cr.BankName, cr.BankCode, cr.BankDraftNo, 
                   cat.Fee, cat.Amount, c.Address, Case when c.HasTaxExempted = 1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end
                   from Contractors c
                   Inner Join Category cat
                   ON Cat.ID= c.ContractorType_ID
                   Inner Join ContractorRenewal cr
                   ON cr.Contractor_ID= c.ContractorID
                   Inner Join PecCategories pcat
                   ON pcat.ID= c.PECCategoryID


                   Select Documents.DocumentID, Documents.Name from DocumentContractor dc
                   Inner Join Documents
                   ON Documents.DocumentID= dc.Doc_ID
                   where dc.Contractor_ID= @GC_ID

                   Select sc.SpecializationID, sc.Name 'SpecializationName', sc.SpecializationCode, spc.Contractor_ID from SpecializationCodes sc
                   INNER JOIN SpecializationCodeContractor spc
                   ON sc.SpecializationID= spc.SP_ID


END
```

Dataset:

[image]

Comment: You get results from first part that big one join (FIRST SELECT) and from other two SELECT'S YOU ARE NOT GETTING ANY DATA?

Comment: When you execute the SP, is it returning 3 result sets? If not then last 2 select queries are not fetching results due to join condition or non-availability of records.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure cannot output more than one result set, hence you only get results from the first query.

If you want data from all queries, you need to make it into one query...

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
SELECT c.Name
      ,c.FatherName
      ,c.Farm
      ,cat.Name AS 'Cat'
      ,c.CNIC
      ,c.EnlistmentNo
      ,c.ContactNo
      ,CONVERT(DATE,c.RegistrationDate,106) AS RegistrationDate
      ,c.Email
      ,pcat.Name AS 'PECCat'
      ,c.PECCategoryNo AS 'PECLicenseNo'
      ,c.PECReceiptNo
      ,c.ExpectedDate
      ,c.CNWEnlistmentNo
      ,c.NTN
      ,cr.BankName
      ,cr.BankCode
      ,cr.BankDraftNo
      ,cat.Fee
      ,cat.Amount
      ,c.Address
      ,CASE WHEN c.HasTaxExempted = 1
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
        END AS 'HasTaxExempted'
      ,doc.DocumentId
      ,doc.[Name] AS DocumentName
      ,sc.SpecializationID
      ,sc.[Name] AS SpecializationName
      ,sc.SpecializationCode
      ,c.ContractorID
  FROM Contractors AS c
 INNER JOIN [Category] AS cat
         ON cat.ID = c.ContractorType_ID
 INNER JOIN ContractorRenewal AS cr
         ON cr.Contractor_ID = c.ContractorID
 INNER JOIN PecCategories AS pcat
         ON pcat.ID = c.PECCategoryID
 -- Using LEFT OUTER JOIN, in case you have no data
 LEFT OUTER JOIN DocumentContractor AS dc
         ON dc.Contractor_ID = c.ContractorID
 INNER JOIN Documents AS doc
         ON doc.DocumentId = dc.Doc_ID
 -- Using LEFT OUTER JOIN, in case you have no data
 LEFT OUTER JOIN SpecializationCodeContractor AS scc
         ON scc.Contractor_ID = c.ContractorId
 INNER JOIN SpecializationCodes AS sc
         ON sc.SpecializationID = scc.SP_ID;
```